# Radiator "Stop Leak" for faucet?

Tags: plumbing

I have an under-sink hot water dispenser/heater.  The faucet for this (which has three connections - one for cold in, one for cold out back to tank, and one for hot water in) started leaking recently, after ~10 years of service.

On inspection, I see that the casting has a hairline crack in it, which is the source of the leak.  It turns out these things are pretty expensive, so I'm wondering if there is some way to repair it.  A surface treatment like epoxy would not work here.  Is there some kind of 'stop-leak' product, of the type used for radiators, etc., that is approved for potable water use?  Or perhaps a water-thin sealant (cyanoacrylate, e.g.) that would permeate the entire crack and seal it?

Comment: What material is it? Some kind of metal? Or some type of plastic? Why do you say that epoxy wouldn't work?

Comment: @MikeB, "casting" implies metal. Plastic is not cast, to my knowledge.

Comment: If it is made of metal soldering MAY work and brazing probably would - subject to the repairer having the skill and luck to not destroy the valve in the process.

Comment: @isherwood actually, plastic resin casting is a big industry with many applications.

Comment: Is the split part circular and accessible all round? If so, ten wraps of PTFE tape and a tight jubilee clip might suffice. At least that is OK with potable water, non-invasive, removable if no use, and cheap. A shim of tin can between the PTFE and clip would spread the pressure better, too.

Answer (score 13):

Practically speaking, no, replacement is the only reliable repair. A cracked housing for a valve is very difficult to repair while retaining the function of the valve. Also, the crack may suddenly get larger and increase the rate of the leak, causing extensive water damage that will cost a good deal more, so you should shut the heater down and turn off the water supply to it until you get it fixed.

As for products:

Your title mentions **[radiator stop leak](https://penriteoil.com.au/assets/msds/Radiator_Stop_Leak-GHS_SDS_2021_08_16.pdf)**, which is very much [not a thing](https://tech-beac.com/sites/default/files/support-document/MSDS-LIQUI-MOLY-RadiatorStop-Leak.pdf) that should ever contact potable water fittings. Certainly the first two examples I've linked to can be seen to mention that the product is, in fact **poisonous.**

Answer (score 8):

It needs replacement.

Even if that type of product would seal the faucet body properly, it would also clog several things that *shouldn't* be, like the disk valves and other moving components. It's not a viable solution.

You also run the risk of a leak recurring when you're not around to detect it. Even if the current leak only occurs during operation, such a crack can propagate to other areas, maybe letting go and doing costly damage.

Answer (score 3):

Added: People have expressed doubts about this advice, and rightly so.
I assume that anyone interested will read the whole answer and weigh the advice given.
I'd follow my advice. Others may choose not to :-) .

---

If the valve is made of metal, soldering MAY work and brazing probably would - subject to the repairer having the skill and luck to not destroy the valve in the process.

If made of plastic, "plastic welding" with a hot iron or an airgun and smoothing tool will work in some cases.

As this is a situation where a successful repair is a "win" and a failed repair is probably no worse than not having tried, trying seems in order.
I'd certainly try if it was mine.

I'm aware that my advice is contrary to that of other people.
I'm old. 'I fix stuff' and it stays fixed often enough to usually be worth trying. Knowing (or trying to know) the likely limits in a given case helps.

In each situation, ask, 'Does it seem reasonably likely that this repair will withstand the pressure / vibration /  temperature / torque/ weight ... in this case?'
The value of "likely" varies :-).

Comment: Preceded by disassembling the valve so as not to overheat the seals while soldering or brazing. Followed by re-machining the interior surfaces so they actually seal again. If you have a full machine shop and count your time as worth nothing, it's dubious. Without those preconditions, it's not a *practical* approach.

Comment: A failed repair can lead to expensive water damage, and insurance company might not be happy with obvious signs of DIY fix.

Comment: I would down vote this, however, it does come with disclaimers about it being difficult and possibly not working. I would suggest moving those to the top - not everyone has enough attention span to read 5 whole paragraphs...

Comment: @FreeMan I agree about attention spans. I also consider that anyone asking this question and considering a repair is certain to read the whole answer. || I've added an introductory paragraph.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You're brave putting your phone number and email address in your bio...that or you're trolling spammers - can't decide

Comment: @matt.  I get an ongoing trickle of interesting or useful emails. No phone calls yet. || I had one very bad experience some years back from a hater who did not use either of the above. They took a UK ped...le "hunter" page with details of a conversation between a hunter posing as a young teenager and a pervert. (The original was easily found subsequently). They dded my name and some personal details (some imcorrect) and posteed it to SEE. It wa only up for about 20 minites, but in that time it got scraped and spread to many websites. Because of the way it was worded and the way many sites ..

Comment: ... display an index list it appeared in many many web searches using a range of electronic terms. It took some years for them all to vanish. I was not an SEEE  moderator then. If Id known then how the system works I may have been able to roughly localise the sender. As it is I have a strong suspiciaon re ID but no proof. (A man who decided to hate me long ago on another electronic site (for reasons unrelated to electronics but probably clear from my bio :-) and who appears to have some form of mental illness.) So it goes. All gone now. And the deleted SE entry also disappeared some while ago.

Comment: I would also consider looking at the "self amalgamating tape" based pipe repair kits. Never pretty, but that's someone else's decision.